# How to build kernel and kernel modules for specific kernel version magic?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module

I need to build kernel to have vermagic

```
3.10.28-gbc1b510-33899-g9fa745e SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7
```

but after building and verification some module via modinfo it displays

```
3.10.28 preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv6
```

Looks like I can't load module because different vermagic. How to build kernel and modules for vermagic to be axactly the same ?. I'm using buildroot.

I created this shell script in order to prepare for build

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/bin:/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/host/bin:/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/host/sbin:/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/host/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/host/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/host/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig
exec /bin/bash
```

then I enter folder

```
/buildroot-2018.02.3/output/build/linux-3.10.28/
```

and

```
make distclean
make clean
```

then copy .config and

```
make ARCH=arm menuconfig
```

and

```
make -j9 ARCH=arm
```

I'm using original kernel konfig with additionaly selected a few options to build as modules without modifications of any other.

Comment: I know where to add -gbc1b510-33899-g9fa745e but I don't know why modules are without SMP - it's selected in kernel .config and don't know why it builds for armv6 not armv7

Comment: are you crosscompiling?

Comment: yes I'm corss compiling using buildroot's gcc. Building for arm on PC

Comment: I'd try after adding -march=armv7 to CFLAGS in Makefile in linux source foder but it didn't wont to compile

Comment: Try smth like `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- CFLAGS=-march=armv7-a`. You need to pass for which architecture the compiler is going to compile. This defaults i guess to armv6, but you can switch that with `-march` or `-mcpu` .

Comment: and what about that SMP ?. I didn't have it in my modules in vermagic

Comment: I'd set path to cross compiler i kernel .config file. cross prefix option

Comment: Now it compiles with CFLAGS=-march=armv7-a. Just a moment I'll see the result

Comment: now it is 3.10.28-gbc1b510-33899-g9fa745e preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv6. The command was make -j9 ARCH=arm CFLAGS=-march=armv7-a

Comment: Buh, that `-a` in `-march=armv7-a` is a typo. Anyway, you should know what switches you need for your target architecture. SMP i guess is support for multiple processors, it is enabled in kernel config not by the compiler,

Comment: You can inspect what make will run with dry-run `make -n`, no need to recompile the kernel, just look if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc is invoked with correct CFLAGS in `make -n`

Comment: device description says that is has Qualcomm Snapdragon 410 8916 processor. What is the correct march switch for compilation ?. It didn't want to compile with armv7 but it compiled with armv7-a (I replaced these entries in makefile) but now vermagic is 3.10.28-gbc1b510-33899-g9fa745e preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8

Comment: Dunno, [wiki](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Snapdragon#Snapdragon_410) sais 410 is armv8. For SMP, set CONFIG_SMP in your kenrel config

Comment: but I got armv7 returned by modinfo run on original .ko modules in original tablet firmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is linux-3.10.28/arch/arm/Makefile file. In this file there are those defines

```
arch-$(CONFIG_CPU_32v7)     :=-D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=7 $(call cc-option,-march=armv7-a,-march=armv5t -Wa$(comma)-march=armv7-a)
arch-$(CONFIG_CPU_32v6)     :=-D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=6 $(call cc-option,-march=armv6,-march=armv5t -Wa$(comma)-march=armv6)
```

I found suggestion somewhere which lead me to replace

```
arch-$(CONFIG_CPU_32v6)     :=-D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=6 $(call cc-option,-march=armv6,-march=armv5t -Wa$(comma)-march=armv6)
```

with

```
arch-$(CONFIG_CPU_32v6)     :=-D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=7 $(call cc-option,-march=armv7-a,-march=armv5t -Wa$(comma)-march=armv7-a)
```

I olso uncommented these two:

```
tune-$(CONFIG_CPU_V6)       :=$(call cc-option,-mtune=arm1136j-s,-mtune=strongarm)
tune-$(CONFIG_CPU_V6K)      :=$(call cc-option,-mtune=arm1136j-s,-mtune=strongarm)
```

I added

```
-gbc1b510-33899-g9fa745e SMP
```

as local_version in kernel .config

and now version string print by modinfo is the same.